# How to prevent Windows 10 from reading from an idle hard disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive

My internal SATA hdd is a bit loud so i only want it spinning when i need it.

Windows 10 idle function works for a bit but my hdd spins up again every ~10min. This might be due to my antivirus or other program, i'm not sure. I can look into this more but I prefer to not have to manually check every program (current and future) to see if they read from the hard disk every so often.

So is there a way to just force the hdd to remain idle until i manually wake it up? Software solutions are preferred.

Comment: Is the system installed in that drive? If so then no.

Answer (score 0):

If the drive is used only infrequently, and is not the Windows system drive, [unmount it](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/158668-how-mount-unmount-drive-volume-windows.html). This can cause problems if you have Windows folders such as *Documents*, *Music* or *Pictures* on that drive, and the drive letter might be unavailbale if another device, e.g., USB flash drive, is plugged in while the noisy drive is unmounted and "steals" that letter.

If you decide it's still worth doing, the easiest way to do this is to create two batch files, the first to unmount and the second to mount the drive again.

```
  mountvol <drive letter>: /P

  mountvol <drive letter>: <Volume GUID>
```

Save these as text files with extension *bat*, and run as Administrator. Create shortcuts to them, and set the properties of the shortcuts to run as Administrator, to avoid having to use the context menu.

Perhaps it would be more effective to simply mount the HDD on a home-made rubber standoff to silence it.